# Dependency Field validation in Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, bean-validation

Apache camel bean validation:

I have one field dependent on another can some one help me how to Validate e.g. If manufacturer field data is **SPECIFIC** then **licensePlate** field is mandatory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<constraint-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping">
    <default-package>org.apache.camel.component.bean.validator</default-package>

    <bean class="CarWithoutAnnotations" ignore-annotations="true">
        <field name="manufacturer">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull" />
        </field>

        <field name="licensePlate">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull" />

         </field>
    </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```

Comment: Look at the bean-validation specification/documentation what/how to do that.

Comment: Thanks Ibsen. I achieved this with org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ScriptAssert where cross field validation works.

Answer (score 1):

Please use org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ScriptAssert for cross field validation.